# Groovy:XMl: How to remove and replace child tag with in a chid tag

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have an xml request i need to create another xml with request with this request without certain  child tags

```
String requestXml = """
<School>
    <Classes>
        <Class>
           <Teachers>
              <Name>Rama</Name>
              <Name>Indhu</Name>
           </Teachers>
           <Name>Anil</Name>
           <RollNumber>16</RollNumber>
        </Class>
        <Class>
            <Teachers>
              <Name>Nisha</Name>
              <Name>Ram</Name>
           </Teachers>
           <Name>manu</Name>
           <RollNumber>21</RollNumber>
        </Class>
   </Classes>
</School>
"""
```

this is the request which i have,i need to create another request with this one and it would be like this in myRequest

```
String myRequest = """
<School>
   <Classes>
      <Class>
         <Name>Anil</Name>
         <RollNumber>16</RollNumber>
      </Class>
      <Class>
         <Name>manu</Name>
         <RollNumber>21</RollNumber>
      </Classes>
</School>
"""
```

how can i achive this by using

```
parsed = new XmlSlurper (false, false).parseText( requestXml )

String myRequest = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    mkp.yield parsed.Classes.children()
}
```

How can i remove the `<Teachers>` tag? also how to remove the tag `<RollNumber>21</RollNumber>` and insert new tag `<Rank>2</Rank>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`replaceNode()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#replaceNode%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) on the node that is needed to be removed. It applies to all `Teachers` nodes under `Classes` parent.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xml = '''
<School>
    <Classes>
        <Class>
           <Teachers>
              <Name>Rama</Name>
              <Name>Indhu</Name>
           </Teachers>
           <Name>Anil</Name>
           <RollNumber>16</RollNumber>
        </Class>
        <Class>
            <Teachers>
              <Name>Nisha</Name>
              <Name>Ram</Name>
           </Teachers>
           <Name>manu</Name>
           <RollNumber>21</RollNumber>
        </Class>
   </Classes>
</School>
'''

def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

//Remove all Teachers node
parsed.Classes.Class.Teachers.replaceNode { }

XmlUtil.serialize( parsed )
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. is it possible to remove tag roll number and add a new tag <Rank>2</Rank> inside this..?

Comment: `parsed.Classes.Class.RollNumber.replaceNode { 'Rank' 2 }`? @user3395072